# Find conversations between users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I need an ActiveRecord query to find conversations for current_user and any another user

Conversations can have many users. I need to set users ids in that query(it can be two or more users).

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :conversations
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join and put the query as a hash

```
Conversation.joins(:users).where(conversation_attr: some_value, users: { id:  current_user.id })
```

or

```
Conversation.joins(:users).where(conversation_attr: some_value, users: { id:  [user_id1, user_id2, ...]})
```

Comment: For getting conversations and specific users would work, but for getting a specific conversation between two specific users or more, I think maybe something's missing there.

Comment: Not sure what defines the specific conversations, but you can extend the where clause with additional conversation query attributes. Something like: 
Conversation.joins(:users).where( conversation_attr: some_value, users: { id:  [user_id1, user_id2, ...]})

Comment: I made join table user_conversations between user and conversation. **Conversation.joins(:user_conversations).where(user_conversations: { user_id: user_ids }).group('conversations.id').having("COUNT(user_conversations.user_id) = #{user_ids.size}").to_a**